# Responsive mosaic of images as backgrounds in CSS/HTML - borders and capture texts needed

Tags: html, css

I have created a responsive mosaic of images (as div backgrounds). The problem is that I can not add borders and caption texts. In the foto below you can see the actual result and desired result.

[image]

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2a4zh38/20/)

I need borders:

**#foto1** - `border-right:2px solid #fff;`

**#foto2** - `border-bottom:2px solid #fff;`

I add borders to `#foto1` and `#foto3` but they don' t appear.

Containers `.caption` should contain caption text. When I enter some text, the container changes it's height. I need it to stay the same height..

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
<div class="tablerow">

<div class="tablecell">

<a href="#">
<div id="foto1" style="padding-top:100%;background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/simplistic-collection-icons-by-mediajon/png/48x48/lock.png) center no-repeat,url(https://www.canarias7.es/binrepository/768x513/0c33/768d432/none/11314/UVTR/image_content_3669106_20180619165415.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:auto, cover;"> 
<div class="caption">
</div>
</div>
</a>

</div>
<div class="tablecell">

<a href="#">
<div id="foto2" style="padding-top:50%;background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/simplistic-collection-icons-by-mediajon/png/48x48/lock.png) center no-repeat,url(https://www.canarias7.es/binrepository/768x513/0c0/768d432/none/11314/VMNM/180731ftv-carretera-corralejo-8melian_3847760_20180804162359.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:auto, cover;">
<div class="caption">
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#">
<div id="foto3" style="padding-top:50%;background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/simplistic-collection-icons-by-mediajon/png/48x48/lock.png) center no-repeat,url(https://www.canarias7.es/binrepository/768x512/0c40/768d432/none/11314/TKDX/papas-diez-tipos_3850905_20180807065646.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:auto, cover;"> 
<div class="caption">
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table{display:table;width:70%;}
.tablerow{display:table-row;}
.tablecell{display:table-cell;width:50%;vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: You'll need to **position** the caption div over the image...there are hundreds of questions on SO about overlaying text on images.

Comment: use position absolute for the text divs, and place them in the tablecell classes. You don't actually need borders there, you need some spacing between elements, use paddings.

Comment: Containers .caption should contain caption text.-- for this add CSS on .caption{text-transform:uppercase}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write some CSS

```css
.table {
  display:table;
  width:70%; }
.tablerow {
  display:table-row;
}
.tablecell {
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.tablecell a div:not (.caption) {
  position:relative;
}
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
#foto1 {
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
}
#foto2 {
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tablerow">
    <div class="tablecell">
      <a href="#">
        <div id="foto1" style="padding-top:100%;background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/simplistic-collection-icons-by-mediajon/png/48x48/lock.png) center no-repeat,url(https://www.canarias7.es/binrepository/768x513/0c33/768d432/none/11314/UVTR/image_content_3669106_20180619165415.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:auto, cover;"> 
          <div class="caption">caption Text</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="tablecell">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="foto2" style="padding-top:50%;background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/simplistic-collection-icons-by-mediajon/png/48x48/lock.png) center no-repeat,url(https://www.canarias7.es/binrepository/768x513/0c0/768d432/none/11314/VMNM/180731ftv-carretera-corralejo-8melian_3847760_20180804162359.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:auto, cover;">
      <div class="caption">caption Text</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
     <div id="foto3" style="padding-top:50%;background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/simplistic-collection-icons-by-mediajon/png/48x48/lock.png) center no-repeat,url(https://www.canarias7.es/binrepository/768x512/0c40/768d432/none/11314/TKDX/papas-diez-tipos_3850905_20180807065646.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:auto, cover;"> 
      <div class="caption">caption Text</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c2a4zh38/39/

Comment: Works perfectly. The only problem is the border on #foto2. Try to increase it to see the problem better, for example: #foto2{border-bottom:20px solid #fff;} The border increases height. Is there any way to keep the container with foto2 and foto3 of the same height asthe container with photo1?

Comment: Solved it by adding "padding-bottom:2px;" to "photo1".